# Firestore security rules with set {merge}

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my **Firestore** data I have the following

- ItemID

  - amountOfItemsToPurchase: 1
  - itemsLeft: 3

If a user wants to update the items to purchase for the same **ItemID** or create the document if the **ItemID** is not present, I use `set(, {merge:true}`, however in terms of the **Firestore Security rules** things get complicated.

I've written the following test:

```
const initialUserDoc = adminFirestore.collection("Users").doc(VALID_USER_ID).collection("Cart").doc(documentID);
            await initialUserDoc.set({
                "amountOfItemsToPurchase": 1,
                "itemsLeft": 3
            });
    
            // Get the user's node and grab the example user
            const userTestRef = db.collection("Users").doc(VALID_USER_ID).collection("Cart").doc(documentID);
    
            await firebase.assertFails(userTestRef.set({
                "amountOfItemsToPurchase": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1000),
    
            }, {merge: true}));
```

This test results in the following: `Error: Expected request to fail, but it succeeded`

What I want for every scenario (update or create), to avoid that the `amountOfItemsToPurchase` exceeds the `itemsLeft`,  for that I use the following:
`request.resource.data.amountOfItemsToPurchase <= request.resource.data.itemsLeft` => This will be in the **allow create** portion.

This rises the following:
Does the **allow create** or the allow update** will be called? and also why is not taking into account the `itemsLeft` variable

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full rules that aren't working the way you expect, along with the client code that performs the update.  I don't see why your condition wouldn't work for updates the same way it does for creates, as long as you call out that operation.  In either case, you are rejecting the new contents of the document that don't satisfy your condition.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my question

Comment: Where are you full rules?  Please be certain that what you're trying to do doesn't actually just work with update in addition to create.  I was proposing that they should work fine.  An update with merge is either a create when the document is first created, or an update if it already existed.  There is nothing ambiguous about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description and the comments, your security rule looks OK.
Let me write it for futher discussion:

```
match /items/{id} {
    allow create, update: 
        if request.resource.data.amountOfItemsToPurchase < request.resource.data.itemsLeft;
}
```

First gotcha: use `request.resource` to be able to read the value of the field *after* the update.

Second gotcha: when using `set`, the `FieldValue.increment` sentinel does *not increment* but sets the value. You should use the `update` function to actually increment the value.

Third gotcha: `FieldValue.increment` with `set` function and `{merge: true}` *does increment* the value!

So in the end the rule works fine as is, I can confirm it works for me.